# Ubuntu 10.04 (LTS) DomU on Debian Wheezy Dom0 Xen 4

Tags: ubuntu, debian, xen, ubuntu-10.04

I have been forced to move from a

Centos Dom0

xen 3

Centos + Ubuntu Lucid DomUs

To

Debian Wheezy Dom0

Xen 4

Ubuntu Lucid DomUs

However although I can create new DomUs on wheezy I cannot get them to boot.

pygrub returns Error: Bootloader didn't return any data

I have ensured that the disks are the correct way around in the xen.cfg and also that the grub config is correct.

If I try to run pygrub manually

eg
/usr/bin/pygrub /dev/volgroup/disk

I get

Illegal instruction

can anyone offer me any advice on this?

Thanks

Matt

Comment: How do you create domUs? Can you show /boot/grub/menu.lst or grub.cfg from your domU? And domU.cfg file too.

Answer (score 1):

A few things to try:

1) Boot the guests by using kernel and ramdisk instead of bootloader in the domU config file. You can use the dom0 kernel and ramdisk

2) Try PV-Grub ( http://wiki.xen.org/wiki/PVGrub_HowTo )

3) Boot the guests HVM and use the PV on HVM drivers ( http://wiki.xen.org/wiki/Using_Xen_PV_Drivers_on_HVM_Guest + http://wiki.xen.org/wiki/XenLinuxPVonHVMdrivers )